# Is 'have difficulties' correct?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, collocations

> But it is far enough away that early explorers had difficulty/difficulties finding it.

What should I choose completing the exam task? Are both plural and singular correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. Both plural and singular can be used.

The better way to say it would be:

> But it is far enough away that early explorers had **difficulties**
>   finding it.

This shows all the explorers faced different difficulties.

Comment: Although both are grammatical, I would prefer the plural, 'difficulties'. That suggests that different explorers had different difficulties, while the singular, 'difficulty', suggests (I guess less realistically) that all explorers had the same difficulty.